# NSApplication windows property - windows not removed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a NSWindow/Controller that I display modal. It has a "Close" button hooked up to an action like this:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [self.window orderOut:sender];
    [self.window close];

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
}
```

From my main window, I display the modal:

```
- (IBAction)modal:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Before: %lu", [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]);

    ModalWindowController *modal = [[ModalWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ModalWindowController"];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:modal.window];

    NSLog(@"After: %lu", [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]);
}
```

I open and close the modal a few times, and the output is like this:

```
2013-01-17 14:36:08.071 Modals[3666:303] Before: 1
2013-01-17 14:36:08.962 Modals[3666:303] After: 2
2013-01-17 14:36:09.578 Modals[3666:303] Before: 2
2013-01-17 14:36:11.009 Modals[3666:303] After: 3
2013-01-17 14:36:12.108 Modals[3666:303] Before: 3
2013-01-17 14:36:12.910 Modals[3666:303] After: 4
```

So, *[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]* only ever *increases*.

I would expect it to increase and decrease as I open and close the modal window. My application uses ARC. Can someone explain this to me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's does `[window isReleasedWhenClosed]` return? Is the modal showing as a sheet, or a top-level modal popup?

Comment: Window was set to release when closed. It turns out, I did not have ARC enabled on this project so the controller was still being retained. Thank you!

Comment: OK, so the problem was you thought you were using ARC, but weren't? Yeah, that will lead to all kinds of leaks…

Comment: I don't work in XCode much, and for some reason I had it in my head that ARC was enabled by default these days

Comment: It is. Unless you're using a pretty old version of Xcode (in which case "these days" isn't relevant), when you create a New Project, and select Cocoa Application, the "Use Automatic Reference Counting" checkbox is on by default. Unless you turn it off, you get it. (And, unlike Xcode 3, I don't think there's even any way to change the defaults in your preferences…)

Comment: @abarnert When I choose New Project > Cocoa Application, it's unchecked. My XCode is 4.5.2. If it's possible to change that default setting, I certainly didn't do it - even if I knew how, I only built my system in October and definitely didn't change it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing your window, but that's not deallocating it because your window controller `ModalWindowController` is still retaining it. I don't see anything in your sample to indicate the window controller is being released.

The simplest answer to give you is to have you release your window controller following your call to `-runModalForWindow:`.

What you may be expecting is the window controller to close when your window does. That's something you have to make happen yourself. From "Window Closing Behavior," in Apple's documentation:

> If you want the closing of a window to make both window and window
>   controller go away when it isn’t part of a document, your subclass of
>   NSWindowController can observe NSWindowWillCloseNotification or, as
>   the window delegate, implement the windowWillClose: method and include
>   the following line of code in your implementation: "[self autorelease];"

In your scenario, this might not be the best approach, because you'd wind up disposing of both your window controller and window before you get a chance to call `-stopModal`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Adding the call to [modal release] fixes things... It turns out, I did not have ARC enabled for the project. D'oh! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Give a look to this *NSWindow* method:

```
- (void)setReleasedWhenClosed:(BOOL)releasedWhenClosed;
```

If you set it to *YES* your window will be released when closed. But be careful that when the count is to zero it will be deallocated.

Comment: Window was set to release when closed. It turns out, I did not have ARC enabled on this project so the controller was still being retained. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For the Swift 5 people, this works for me. In this case I want to close every window properly, unless it's the last one, in which case I want it to hide

```
  func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    sender.isReleasedWhenClosed = true
    if NSApp.windows.count > 1 {
        return true
    }
    NSApp.hide(nil)
    return false
}
```

Comment: You're doing this in the wrong place. You should set this property in the XIB/storyboard file, or when you (manually) create the window using alloc/init.

Comment: To elaborate: There may be other windows in your process managed by AppKit itself (like the About, Fonts or Colors panels), and randomly changing them to releasedWhenClosed may cause them to be released while AppKit's code to manage them thinks they're just hidden. Also, windowShouldClose _should_ only check if it's OK to close one particular window, it shouldn't actually modify that window (not to mention other windows) in significant ways. Finally, why do you only allow closing the window if it's the last one? And why do you hide the app (that does not close any windows, nor free memory)?