# Cocoa get number of open windows

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am making a simple app that will hide open windows, but I want to add a text box that will tell the number of open windows, what cocoa function do I need for this? is there a function in `nswindow` that I could use?

Comment: You have to use the ```CGWindow``` API. Take a look at Apple's [Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int windowCount = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] count];
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: That will give you the count of your own app's windows, but not other apps windows (which is what I suspect Kyle wants to do).

Comment: I want to tell the number of open windows for other applications.

Comment: @kylek add it anywhere you want the count of your application's windows. But Michael is right -- if you're trying to count windows owned by other applications, this won't help. You're not going to find an easy way to count or close windows that aren't yours -- there may be sneaky ways, but in general applications are expected not to mess with each other's windows, files, etc.

Comment: Caution: This may include windows that have been closed by the user in the count. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14386802/12484